# How to give attribution to Creative Commons pictures in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, beamer

I am making a presentation in org-mode and have some creative commons pictures that I need to give attribution for.

I have tried using a footnote with the reference but as the picture is in the right column of a two column slide, the reference just runs off the slide and looks messy.

Does anyone have a method that they use in org-mode that gives attribution in a neat and clear way?

Comment: Probably not the elaborate solution you are looking for, but you could simply use a caption? With `#+CAPTION: Some caption` right above the link to the image.

Comment: @EFLS I feel captioning the picture draws attention away from the points on the slide (the attribution reference is quite long for the pictures i am using) . Was thinking more along the lines of a reference type setup with a number by the picture and a numbered picture list at the end of the presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a couple of different kinds of citations:

1. In text:

   ```
   @@l:\\{\footnotesize@@ [[doi:10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.041601][PRL 114 (2015) 041601]] @@l:}@@
   ```
2. As a footnote (this is probably better suited for images): `\footnotemark` somewhere in the text, and the following at the end

   ```
   @@l:\footnotetext{@@[[arxiv:1205.1444][arxiv:1205.1444]]@@l:}@@
   ```

The slide with these two references looks like this:
[image: Example slide with references]

Instead of manually handling the text, you could also use the usual `\cite` command, and add a full bibliography in the appendix.  I guess for that just add a `\printbibliography` at the end of the appendix.

Comment: Thanks. This gives me a couple of options to work with.